# Is there a way to create subdomain like url redirection using .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I want to write a .htaccess from which the following action should be done.

I have domain like

```
www.xyz.com
```

and am putting many articles on that. 
so it wil become

```
www.xyz.com/article1-tutorial/
www.xyz.com/article2-tutorial/
www.xyz.com/article3-tutorial/
```

But instead of that i need like this.

```
www.article1-tutorial.xyz.com/
www.article2-tutorial.xyz.com/
www.article3-tutorial.xyz.com/
```

Please help to find the solution. I know we cant go for subdomain concept and only the way is redirection. So whats is the solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need something like this in your apache.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80 >
        ServerName automated_domains
        ServerAlias *.xyz.com
        VirtualDocumentRoot /home/xyzcom/website/
</VirtualHost>
```

Then in the PHP file you put in `/home/xyzcom/website`, you can get the domain that was actually called in the `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` variable.

Hope this helps!

KKovacs

Comment: Hi, thanks for your Reply here. this "ServerName automated_domains" , is this domain name like(xyz.com) or actual server name(unlimitedsubdomains). I will try this one.

Answer (score 2):

You can use apache's mod rewrite like so:

```
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !www.domain.com$ [NC]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?([a-z0-9-]+).domain.com [NC]
   RewriteRule (.*) %2/$1 [L]
```

when a user goes to http://article1-tutorial.domain.com/
server internaly rewrites therequest to http://www.domain.com/article1-tutorial

Comment: You forgot, that A record for subdomains at the DNS must be point to the domain.com and have value "*"

Comment: thanks for your reply. And what you meant by "A record for subdomains at the DNS must be point to the domain.com and have value "*" ", 

I will try it out.

Comment: @antyrat "A record for subdomains at the DNS must be point to the domain.com and have value "*" What you meant by this line?

Comment: I mean that all subdomains mus be point to the main domain. If so you can easy show article to user according to the HTTP_HOST value.

Answer (score 1):

Can you use the reverse proxy engine of apache?

[Reverse Proxying with Apache](http://www.apachetutor.org/admin/reverseproxies)